# How can I count the number of occurrences of a user inputed element in a string?

Tags: c++, string, count, element

How can I count the number of occurrences of a user inputed element in a string?
Example:

Input:
***adseddsdf***
Input:
***a***
Output:
***1***

Comment: What do you think you can do? What have you tried to do?

Comment: @Ico if you can clarify your question, you are welcome to [edit] it.

Comment: #include<iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
string str1;
string str2="1";
cin>>str1;
str1.replace(2,1,str2);
cout<<str1;
}

Comment: This should be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You've edited this question to change it to an entirely different one. That is not appropriate here. I would suggest that you revert your edit to go back to the original question and then accept the correct answer to your original question given by Nick Khrapov. If you want to ask this new question, do so as a new question.

Comment: I have rolled back the edits that invalidated the supplied answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can count it yourself or use stl

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    constexpr char chFind = 'a';
    std::string str = "abcabca";

    // first solution
    size_t num1 = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        if (str[i] == chFind)
            num1++;

    // second solution
    size_t num2 = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), chFind);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you but  im a beginner and i  dont understnands any of the stuff you showed me

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the OP's question - how to handle reporting an error if the input is too short.

Comment: @AviBerger author changed question completely

Comment: @NickKhrapov You are entirely correct. I missed that and another detail. Sorry you got the rug pulled entirely out from under you.

Comment: @AviBerger it's ok, don't worry

Comment: @NickKhrapov your `std::count_if()` example can be simplied using `std::count()` instead, you don't need to use a predicate: `size_t num2 = std::count(str.begin(), str.end(), chFind); `

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, fixed